# Adding swiper t html css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

When I am adding swiper to my HTML the CSS is messed up it is not properly functional.
the margin from the container is disabled after adding the swiper. here is my HTML and JS code:-

```js
let swiper = new Swiper('.portfolio_container', {
  cssMode: true,
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.0.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<h2>Portfolio</h2>
Most recent work
<div class="portfolio_container container swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- ==================PORTFOLIO 1 ============ -->
    <div class="porfolio_content grid swiper-slide">
      <img src="img/portfolio1.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio_img">
      <div class="portfolio_data">
        <h3 class="portfolio_title">Modern Websites</h3>
        <p class="portfolio_description">Websites adaptable to all devices, with UI components and animated interactions. </p>
        <a href="#" class="button button--flex button--small portfolio_button">Demo<i class="uil uil-arrow-right button_icon"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/portfolio3.jpg" alt="" class="">
    <h3>Online Store</h3>
    <p>Websites adaptable to all devices, with UI components and animated interactions. </p>
    <a href=" # ">Demo<i></i></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next ">
    <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b swiper-portfolio-icon "></i>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev ">
    <i class="uil uil-angle-left-b swiper-portfolio-icon "></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination "></div>
```

To add a swiper slide to my portfolio section

Comment: Hey, can you please help me with swiper js in my code here is my GitHub link for the code please help me out   https://github.com/SauravBelwal/Saurravbelwal